# Web automation Stuck with drop down selection

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I'm new to web automation and got stuck at the drop-down selection from the list. Hereby attached source code for reference and help me with the piece of code. Thanks for your help in advance...

I want to select PO Number from the list.

I tried these coding but no luck

tried to select directly.
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-typeahead").GetElementsByTagNam("span")(0).GetElementsByTagNam("pre").innerText = "PO NUMBER"
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("tt-suggestion-1-2 tt-suggestion tt-selectable").Click

ie.document.getElementsByClassName("typeahead")(0).getElementsByClassName("tt-input").Click

Tried to click the dropdown button and then select "PO number" from the list
 ie.document.getElementsByTagName("svg").getElementsByClassName("dropdown-icon").getElementsByClassName("icon ").Click

when i inspect element it goes to input class="tt-input" reference. Kindly help me

Comment: I'm very sorry to tell you that this site is not a free code writing service. Without posting what code you have tried and where you are stuck, we cannot help. --- Read this carefully: Edit your question and provide your code. Do not post that in a comment. Post a comment when you have edited your question.

Comment: As per comment above. Also, please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html; Don't paste as image.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, Thanks for your response. I have edited my comments as per your instruction. Kindly look into my issue and help me